# Unable to use JDO in a GAE background thread

Tags: java, google-app-engine, exception, jdo

I have created a background thread on a Runnable object in Google App Engine like this:

```
BackendService s = new BackendService();
thread = ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread(s);
thread.start();
```

However - when it comes to initialize get the PersistenceManagerFactory , which I do like this:

```
private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactional");
```

I get a classloader exception:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.apphosting.runtime.FatalError: A not-user-defined ClassLoader was set as the thread'scontextClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1a8c4e7
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-f71d5e950ca508ff(Request.java)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:34)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue (using JPA.) The solution that seems to work is to set the class loader in the Runnable manually.

In calling object:

```
private static Thread thread;
private static ClassLoader cl;
```

In calling method:

```
...
cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
thread = ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread(...);
thread.start();
...
```

In Runnable run():

```
thread.setContextClassLoader(cl);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`Thread thread = ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ... 
        ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
        ...
    }
});`
```